# import & structure python modules / classes

Tags: python, google-app-engine, module, gae-module

im working on some basic python stuff within the google app engine and I was unable to figure out the correct way to structure my handlers.

- /main.py
- /project/handlers/__init__.py
- /project/handlers/AccountHandler.py

the AccountHandler is basically a class

```
class AccountHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
```

when im using from project.handlers import AccountHandler
python always give me a

> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

how do i have to name/import/structure my classes?

cheers,
Martin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To quote from [the docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html):

> A module is a file containing Python definitions and statements. The file name is the module name with the suffix `.py` appended.

The `AccountHandler` you are importing is the module `/project/handlers/AccountHandler.py` in this case.  The file `AccountHandler.py` is not callable, and the interpreter tells you this. To call the class you defined in your file just use:

```
from project.handlers.AccountHandler import AccountHandler
# Alternately
# from project.handler import AccountHandler
# AccountHandler.AccountHandler() # will also work.
```

Comment: `<pedantic>` AccountHandler is the name of the module in this case, AccountHandler.py is the name of the file.`</pedantic>`

Comment: *Chuckles* @Laurence -- pedantic note noted.  Is the new verbiage better?  (And thanks!)

Comment: Thanks! Works! How can i import ALl classes/Handlers in the handlers module?

Comment: @magegu -- in this case `handlers` would be a `package`, rather than a module.  You'll want to see http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package  (The short of it is you'll need to add an `__all__ = [ an, array, of, modules, and, names, to, load]` in your `__init__.py` file in `handlers` and then you can do `from project.handlers import *` -- but it would be better to pull out only the ones you need by name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rename `init.py` to `__init__.py`

Comment: He had `__init__.py`. Markdown had just interpreted the underscores as formatting.